# Error message displaying when it shouldnt (School work)

Tags: python

Hi this is school work so please don't just give me the right answer but tell me what I have done wrong so I can go and correct it please.
So my code works fine but there is one problem. When I type "Coin", the error message is displayed after it displays the coin flip. Here is my code:

```
def program():
    error_message = "Answer not recognised!\nMake sure it is spelt right and starts with a capital letter."
    Choice = input("Pick either 'Card' or 'Coin' ")
    if Choice == "Coin":
        import random

        r = random.randint(1,2)
        if r == 1:
            print ("Heads!")
        else:
            print ("Tails!")

    if Choice == "Card":
        import random
        card_number = random.randint(1,13)

        if card_number == 1:
            card_number = "Ace"
        elif card_number == 11:
            card_number = "Jack"
        elif card_number == 12:
            card_number = "Queen"
        elif card_number == 13:

            card_number = "King"

    if Choice == "Card":
        import random
        card_suit = random.randint(1,4)

        if card_suit == 1:
            card_suit = "Hearts"
        elif card_suit == 2:
            card_suit = "Clubs"
        elif card_suit == 3:
            card_suit = "Diamonds"
        else:
            card_suit = "Spades"

    if Choice == "Card":
        print(card_number ,"of" , card_suit)

    #else print error message
    else:
        print(error_message)


while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [yes/no] ') == 'yes'

else:
    print ("The program will now terminate.")
```

I have tried many different ways of trying to get around this but I cant figure it out. Remember this is school work so I would like help but not to be told the answer. Thanks

Comment: There are four `if` statements and one `else` statement in the body of `program()`. Look at which `if` statement the `else` corresponds to.

Comment: Look at the condition of the if/else statement in which the `error_message` is printed.

Comment: Oh I think I understand, it is under the Card choice so if the choice doesn't equal card it will put the error message

Comment: That's right, if you enter anything that isn't "Card" (e.g. "Coin") it will always print the error message.

Comment: Im just having trouble sorting that now

Comment: Well done for asking the right question - i.e. hints where you have gone wrong, rather than someone correcting your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the outermost level of `program()`, you have four separate `if` statements. Each one will execute, one after the other. The `else` is attached to the final `if`.

```
if Choice == "Card":
    print(card_number ,"of" , card_suit)

#else print error message
else:
    print(error_message)
```

When `Choice` is `Coin` then `Choice == "Card"` evaluates false, and so the `else` branch is chosen. You mean to have a single `if` statement like this:

```
def program():
    error_message = ...
    Choice = ...
    if Choice == "Coin":
        # do all the coin related work
    elif Choice == "Card":
        # do all the card related work
    else:
        # handle the error
```

As an aside, it is stylistically preferred to `import` modules once only as the first code in a module.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have helped me lots.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone my code works now, I am now just trying to shorten it. Thank you
Here is the completed code:

```
import random
flag = True
def program():
    error_message = "Answer not recognised!\nMake sure it is spelt right and starts with a capital letter."
    Choice = input("Pick either 'Card' or 'Coin' : ")

    if Choice == "Coin":
        r = random.randint(1,2)
        if r == 1:
            print ("Heads!")
        else:
            print ("Tails!")

    elif Choice == "Card":
        card_number = random.randint(1,13)

        if card_number == 1:
            card_number = "Ace"
        elif card_number == 11:
            card_number = "Jack"
        elif card_number == 12:
            card_number = "Queen"
        elif card_number == 13:
            card_number = "King"

        card_suit = random.randint(1,4)

        if card_suit == 1:
            card_suit = "Hearts"
        elif card_suit == 2:
            card_suit = "Clubs"
        elif card_suit == 3:
            card_suit = "Diamonds"
        else:
            card_suit = "Spades"

        print(card_number ,"of" , card_suit)

    else:
        print(error_message)


while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [yes/no] ') == 'yes'

else:
    print ("The program will now terminate.")
```

I know its messy but it works so now I will focus on shortening it and tidying it up. Thank you